# Integrity constraint for tables not immediately related

Tags: sql, oracle, database-design, constraints

I am a SQL beginner and I can't figure out how to properly create an integrity constraint for situations like this:
[image]

The schema describes a delivery system - each Restaurant offers some items, which can be delivered to customers (outside the visible schema).

The problem comes with the `in_delivery` table - items from menu are registered with the delivery through this table. With the current state of things, it is possible to add a `menu_item` to a `delivery` which is done by a `restaurant`, but that restaurant may not offer the menu_item!

When inserting into `in_delivery`, I need to somehow check, if the `Menu_Item_MenuItem_ID` is present in `offers`, that has `Restaurant_RestaurantID` equal to `RestaurantID` in `Delivery` associated with the table.

I don't know if I can use a foreign key here, because the tables are not "adjacent"..

What comes into mind is to have a `RestaurantID` in `in_delivery`, that would be a foreign key both to `Restaurant` and `Delivery`. Then I could find that in `offers`. Is there a better way?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could enforce your constraint with the following changes:

1. add the `restaurant_id` column in the `in_delivery` table
2. add a unique constraint on `delivery (delivery_id, restaurant_id)` (needed for 3.)
3. change the foreign key from `in_delivery -> delivery` to point to `(delivery_id, restaurant_id)`
4. change the foreign key from `in_delivery -> menu_item` to `in_delivery -> offers`

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use a trigger to check the constraint:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f9593/4)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Restaurants (
  RestaurantID NUMBER(2) PRIMARY KEY,
  Name         VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL
)
/

INSERT INTO Restaurants
          SELECT 1, 'Soylent Green Express' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'Helga''s House of Ribs' FROM DUAL
/

CREATE TABLE Menu_Items (
  Menu_Item_ID NUMBER(2) PRIMARY KEY,
  Name         VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL
)
/

INSERT INTO Menu_Items
          SELECT 1, 'Soylent Green' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'Ribs' FROM DUAL
/

CREATE TABLE Offers (
  RestaurantID NUMBER(2),
  Menu_Item_ID NUMBER(2),
  PRIMARY KEY ( RestaurantID, Menu_Item_ID ),
  FOREIGN KEY ( RestaurantID ) REFERENCES Restaurants ( RestaurantID ),
  FOREIGN KEY ( Menu_Item_ID ) REFERENCES Menu_Items ( Menu_Item_ID )
)
/

INSERT INTO Offers
          SELECT 1, 1 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 2 FROM DUAL
/

CREATE TABLE Deliveries (
  RestaurantID NUMBER(2) NOT NULL,
  Delivery_ID  NUMBER(2) PRIMARY KEY,
  FOREIGN KEY ( RestaurantID ) REFERENCES Restaurants ( RestaurantID )
)
/

INSERT INTO Deliveries
          SELECT 1, 1 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 2 FROM DUAL
/

CREATE TABLE in_delivery (
  Delivery_ID NUMBER(2),
  Menu_Item_ID NUMBER(2),
  PRIMARY KEY ( Delivery_ID, Menu_Item_ID ),
  FOREIGN KEY ( Delivery_ID ) REFERENCES Deliveries ( Delivery_ID ),
  FOREIGN KEY ( Menu_Item_ID ) REFERENCES Menu_Items ( Menu_Item_ID )
)
/
```

Just for ease of reading I've created two useful functions (you would probably want some exception handling in them):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_Delivery_RestaurantID (
  p_Delivery_ID Deliveries.Delivery_ID%TYPE
) RETURN Restaurants.RestaurantID%TYPE
AS
  v_RestaurantID Restaurants.RestaurantID%TYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT RestaurantID
  INTO   v_RestaurantID
  FROM   Deliveries
  WHERE  Delivery_ID = p_Delivery_ID;

  RETURN v_RestaurantID;
END get_Delivery_RestaurantID;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION does_Restaurant_Offer_Item (
  p_RestaurantID Restaurants.RestaurantID%TYPE,
  p_Menu_Item_ID Menu_Items.Menu_Item_ID%TYPE
) RETURN NUMBER
AS
  v_exists NUMBER(1);
BEGIN
  SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS ( SELECT 1 
                            FROM   Offers
                            WHERE  RestaurantID = p_RestaurantID
                            AND    Menu_Item_ID = p_Menu_Item_ID
                          )
         THEN 1
         ELSE 0
         END
  INTO   v_exists
  FROM   DUAL;

  RETURN v_exists;
END does_Restaurant_Offer_Item;
/
```

Then just add a trigger to the table to check that the Restaurant offers the item and, if not, raise an exception.

```
CREATE TRIGGER check_Valid_Delivery_Item
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF Delivery_ID, Menu_Item_ID
ON in_delivery
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   IF does_restaurant_Offer_Item( get_Delivery_RestaurantID( :new.Delivery_ID ), :new.Menu_Item_ID ) = 0
   THEN
     RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20100, 'Invalid Delivery Item');
   END IF;
END check_Valid_Delivery_Item;
/

INSERT INTO in_delivery VALUES( 1, 1 )
/

INSERT INTO in_delivery VALUES( 2, 2 )
/
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT * FROM in_delivery
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f9593/4/0)**:

```
| DELIVERY_ID | MENU_ITEM_ID |
|-------------|--------------|
|           1 |            1 |
|           2 |            2 |
```

If you try to do:

```
INSERT INTO in_delivery VALUES( 1, 2 );
```

Then you get:

```
ORA-20100: Invalid Delivery Item ORA-06512: at "USER_4_F9593.CHECK_VALID_DELIVERY_ITEM", line 4 ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'USER_4_F9593.CHECK_VALID_DELIVERY_ITEM' : INSERT INTO in_delivery VALUES( 1, 2 )
```

Comment: This solution is not entirely robust.  For example, the trigger could give false negative or false positive results because it won't "see" concurrent updates being made by another transactions (for example, to change the restaurant to which a delivery or menu item is related).  To be robust, a trigger-based solution would need to use locking to prevent such updates.

Comment: True, and to OP should consider whether this is likely before employing this option; but it seems unlikely to me (based on assumptions I'm making about the data set) that you will get those changes as I don't know any restaurants which do delivery where the delivery will suddenly shift to another restaurant. @Vincent's answer is the better option but if the design of the tables is immutable then that is not possible this is an option.